# start process in nodejs server , and for each answer send res in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

hey im trying to create some process by get request and return it frequesy in my angular application

i have a request like this >>

```
app.get('/sendMessageToAllUsers',(req,res)=>{
    User.find().then(users=>{
        users.forEach(user=>{
            bot.telegram.sendMessage(user.user_id,req.body.message);
            res.send({message:`Messsage has been sent to ${user.username}`})
        })
    })
})
```

and when i use it on my angular application i want it to add new line in some table with result message,
how can i preform this in angular ?

like

```
<td>res.message</td>
until the process has been done ?
```

Comment: For Angular you want to start here: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @pzaenger what i should look there ?,

Comment: You want to request data from your server. Therefore this guide is worth a look.